# Liquid nitrogen physical properties

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, resource-recommendations, density, viscosity

I am looking for a reference containing the physical properties of liquid nitrogen, in particular density $\rho$ and dynamic viscosity $\mu$ as functions of temperature and pressure.

This is for a fluid mechanics plumbing problem. I am delivering LN2 from a dewar to a cryo-vessel through a complex manifold. Ball park numbers would be a great start, 77 K, 22 and 35 psi, but a look-up table or chart would be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

A super useful reference for these things is the "CRC Handbook of chemistry and physics". I took the following table with the density (remember that N$_2$ has a molar mass of $\sim$ 28 gr mol$^{-1}$) and viscosity from there (note that 35 psi is $\sim$0.24 MPa in SI units):
 [image]